# Java Card DES generator applet output is different from online-tools output

Tags: java, cryptography, javacard

The below applet is written to do a DES encryption/Decryption on the APDU data field :

```
package cryptoPack;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacard.security.CryptoException;
import javacard.security.DESKey;
import javacard.security.KeyBuilder;
import javacardx.crypto.Cipher;

public class CryptoDES extends Applet {

    // Array for the encryption/decryption key
    private byte[] TheDES_Key = { (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00 };

    // Defining required Keys
    DESKey MyDES1Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES, false);
    DESKey MyDES2Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_2KEY, false);
    DESKey MyDES3Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,
            KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_3KEY, false);

    byte ConfiguredKeyLength;

    // Defining required cipher
    Cipher MyCipher;

    // Defining switch case variables for supported instructions = INS in APDU command
    final byte SetKey = (byte) 0xC0;
    final byte OneKeyDES = (byte) 0xC1;
    final byte TwoKeyDES = (byte) 0xC2;
    final byte ThreeKeyDES = (byte) 0xC3;

    // Defining switch case variables for cipher algorithms = P1 in APDU command
    final byte DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1 = (byte) 0x00;
    final byte DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2 = (byte) 0x01;
    final byte DES_CBC_NOPAD = (byte) 0x02;
    final byte DES_CBC_PKCS5 = (byte) 0x03;
    final byte DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1 = (byte) 0x04;
    final byte DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2 = (byte) 0x05;
    final byte DES_ECB_NOPAD = (byte) 0x06;
    final byte DES_ECB_PKCS5 = (byte) 0x07;

    // Defining Proprietary Status Words
    final short KeyInNotSetGood = 0x6440;

    // A flag to be sure that the configured key has the same length that the
    // algorithm needs.

    private CryptoDES() {

    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new CryptoDES().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {

        // Assigning 0 to "ConfiguredKeyLength" to force the user to use ...
        // ... "SetKey" command, after applet selection.
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            ConfiguredKeyLength = 0;
            return;
        }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        // Checking the CLA field in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }

        // Checking the P1 and P2 fields in the APDU command.
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] > 7 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] > 1) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        }

        // Analyzing the command.
        try {

            switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {

            case SetKey:
                SetCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(apdu);
                break;

            case OneKeyDES:

                OneKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);

                break;

            case TwoKeyDES:
                TwoKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            case (byte) ThreeKeyDES:
                ThreeKeyDESCrypto(apdu);
                DoEncryptDecrypt(apdu);
                break;

            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);

            }

        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            ISOException.throwIt(((CryptoException) e).getReason());
        }

    }

    public void SetCryptoKeyAndInitCipher(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Key must has a length of 8, 16 or 24 bytes
        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 8 || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 16
                || buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC] == 24) {
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, TheDES_Key,
                    (short) 0, buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC]);

            ConfiguredKeyLength = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];

        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
        case DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M2, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_NOPAD:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_NOPAD, false);
            break;
        case DES_CBC_PKCS5:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_PKCS5, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_NOPAD:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_NOPAD, false);
            break;
        case DES_ECB_PKCS5:
            MyCipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_ECB_PKCS5, false);
            break;

        }

    }

    public void OneKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not
        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 8) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }
        MyDES1Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void TwoKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not

        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 16) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }
        MyDES2Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES2Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES2Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void ThreeKeyDESCrypto(APDU apdu)
            throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        // Check to see if the configured key is the required key for this ...
        // ... algorithm or not
        if (ConfiguredKeyLength != 24) {
            ISOException.throwIt(KeyInNotSetGood);
        }

        MyDES3Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);

        if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2] == 1) {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES3Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
        } else {
            MyCipher.init(MyDES3Key, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);

        }

    }

    public void DoEncryptDecrypt(APDU apdu) {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();

        byte[] CipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 32,
                JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);

        short datalen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
        if ((datalen % 8) != 0) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_DATA_INVALID);
        }

        MyCipher.doFinal(buffer, (short) 0, datalen, CipheredData, (short) 0);
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(CipheredData, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0,
                datalen);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, datalen);
    }

}
```

The problem is that its output is not equal with online tools. for example I use [this website](http://des.online-domain-tools.com/) to calculate encrypted value of `0x3030303030303030` with a key = `1122334455667788`, and this is output :

[image]

Now I repeat the above encryption with my applet:

```
OpenSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00c0000008112233
4455667788 -s 00c10401083030303030303030
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00 08 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C1 04 01 08 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
8E 43 CF B8 91 02 01 38 .C.....8

OpenSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00c0000008112233
4455667788 -s 00c10501083030303030303030
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00 08 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C1 05 01 08 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
A6 DE 1C D9 1B A9 EE D0 ........

OpenSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00c0000008112233
4455667788 -s 00c10601083030303030303030
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00 08 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C1 06 01 08 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
0B FC BF EE 82 F4 8B 19 ........

OpenSC:: opensc-tool.exe -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00c0000008112233
4455667788 -s 00c10701083030303030303030
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C0 00 00 08 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 C1 07 01 08 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00):
AA 6E 4D 79 E5 0C B1 51 .nMy...Q
```

As I didn't know which one of `DES_ECB_PKCS5`, `DES_ECB_NOPAD`, `DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2` or `DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1` being used by the online tool, I did the encryption with all of them in my card. but the output is different from the online tool.

1. What's wrong?
2. How I can find out which one of the above ciphers, does the online tool use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I didn't know which one of DES_ECB_PKCS5, DES_ECB_NOPAD,
>   DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2 or DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1 being used by the online tool

That´s the problem. Blockmode, padding and other things are very important (and there are so much more than 4 combinations). And in case of online tools, charset stuff (input interpretation in general) is also a problem.

Without knowing the online tool in detail, you won´t get anything right with it.
Just don´t use it and search for standardized test vectors.

Other than that, why you´re using DES!? Stop that.
It´s not secure anymore.

Comment: May I ask you to introduce a standardized test tool/method? (I don't want to use DES, I just digging the card for bugs in crypto methods implementation)

Comment: I´m searching (for test vectors) ... but having a hard time because DES is so old and broken not even Google wants it.

Comment: Thank you. I mark the answer as accepted. I appreciate you if inform me about your search results. Now I try OpenSSL to check the DES crypto methods. I think it has this block/padding modes.

Comment: Yes, it should have everything.

Comment: @Abraham did you implement DES encryption with OpenSSL, and whether you have received the same results as the output of the applet?

Comment: @im_infamous Yes,  I encrypt some random data with DES algorithm using Openssl and using my applet. Results was equal. Why did you asked this?

Comment: @Abraham because I want to reproduce this in my box. Link to github or at least mentioning target Openssl algorithm would be great to save couple hours of time for me and someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

You make encrypt with '00 C1 04 01 08 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30) not 
(30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30);

modify just this
MyCipher.doFinal(buffer, **ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA**, datalen, CipheredData, (short) 0);

Really good worls you make sorry for delay