# Select different padding modes in OpenSSL commands

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, des

I wrote a Java Card applet to do DES encryption/Decryption. The [source code of my  applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148089/java-card-des-generator-applet-output-is-different-from-online-tools-output/30149278?noredirect=1#comment48406460_30149278) (*If you want to use it, consider that Mr Bodewes found some bugs in this source code (those are mentioned in the comments under his answer. So fix it and then use*) have the following functions:

- DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1
- DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2
- DES_ECB_NOPAD
- DES_ECB_PKCS5

I did a comparison between output of my program and output of an online tool, and finally I find them different. So I want to check correctness of my program's output using OpenSSL.

These are results for encrypting `0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30` with key = `0x11 0x22 0x33 0x44 0x55 0x66 0x77 0x88` :

```
::> SendToApplet.exe -key 1122334455667788 -data 3030303030303030

Command::

Data: 3030303030303030
Key : 1122334455667788

Results::

DES_ECB_ISO9797_M1:
8E 43 CF B8 91 02 01 38 .C.....8
DES_ECB_ISO9797_M2:
A6 DE 1C D9 1B A9 EE D0 ........
DES_ECB_NOPAD:
0B FC BF EE 82 F4 8B 19 .......
DES_ECB_PKCS5:
AA 6E 4D 79 E5 0C B1 51 .nMy...Q
```

The question is how I can check to see if these results are OK?

This is list of  *OpenSSL tool* commands and arguments:

```
OpenSSL> ?
openssl:Error: '?' is an invalid command.

Standard commands
asn1parse      ca             ciphers        crl            crl2pkcs7
dgst           dh             dhparam        dsa            dsaparam
ec             ecparam        enc            engine         errstr
gendh          gendsa         genrsa         nseq           ocsp
passwd         pkcs12         pkcs7          pkcs8          prime
rand           req            rsa            rsautl         s_client
s_server       s_time         sess_id        smime          speed
spkac          verify         version        x509

Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
md2            md4            md5            rmd160         sha
sha1

Cipher commands (see the `enc' command for more details)
aes-128-cbc    aes-128-ecb    aes-192-cbc    aes-192-ecb    aes-256-cbc
aes-256-ecb    base64         bf             bf-cbc         bf-cfb
bf-ecb         bf-ofb         cast           cast-cbc       cast5-cbc
cast5-cfb      cast5-ecb      cast5-ofb      des            des-cbc
des-cfb        des-ecb        des-ede        des-ede-cbc    des-ede-cfb
des-ede-ofb    des-ede3       des-ede3-cbc   des-ede3-cfb   des-ede3-ofb
des-ofb        des3           desx           idea           idea-cbc
idea-cfb       idea-ecb       idea-ofb       rc2            rc2-40-cbc
rc2-64-cbc     rc2-cbc        rc2-cfb        rc2-ecb        rc2-ofb
rc4            rc4-40
```

Unfortunately I can see anything related to the Padding modes (i.e *ISO9797_M1*, *ISO9797_M2*, *NOPAD* and *PKCS5*). How I can specify them in my command?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @jww It's about checking the outcome of a programming experiment / API testing. Abraham, maybe you could integrate a link to the code in the question.

Comment: @Maarten - Asking where to find test vectors is off-topic. Asking how to use the OpenSSL commands is off-topic. There are better sites for both of them. For what its worth, I don't think its a bad question; its just better suited for a different site. (And the programming problem he experienced was asked at [Java Card DES generator applet output is different from online-tools output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30148089/608639)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Padding happens before encryption with the block cipher. That means you can always check by decrypting the ciphertext and validating the padding by hand. Using `openssl` you can simply use `-nopad` and `-K <key in hex>` and then validate the output (converting the binary to human readable format first).

Currently we cannot validate because your applet is not returning enough data; you probably forgot to finalize the encryption.

Comment: _your applet is not returning enough data_ **Which kind of data?**  _you probably forgot to finalize the encryption_ **What does this mean?** I posted the source of my applet here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148089/java-card-des-generator-applet-output-is-different-from-online-tools-output/30149278#30149278
May I ask you to help me validate it?

Comment: You forgot that `doFinal` returns the size of the encrypted data. *Because* of padding, the returned data size may be larger than the amount of input. Deterministic schemes always pad, even if you provide exactly one block of data.

Comment: Your results are not OK; you should have identical ciphertext for identical input. ECB doesn't use an IV, it's fully deterministic.

Comment: Is my applet program wrong? (except than replacing `dataLen` `setOutgoinAndSend` method with the output of `doFinal` method)

Comment: I used this command `G:\> openssl des-ecb -in 1.txt -out 2.txt -nosalt -K 1122334455667788 -iv 0 -base64` and convert contents of _2.txt_ to hex form, to check the correctness of my outputs, am I in a right way?

Comment: Looks like it, although obviously `1.txt` and `2.txt` contain binary data (ciphertext is always binary, and the decrypted text may contain the padding on top of the zero characters).

Comment: So it is wrong to put ASCII value of `0x30` (i.e `0`) in the _1.txt_ instead of `30`?(currently contents of _1.txt_ is `00000000`)  With the `-base64` in the end of my command, we have binary in the _2.txt_ still?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no, most of the time you validate using *decryption* rather than encryption. All zeros is text indeed. Not all encryption schemes are deterministic.

Comment: :) What shall I do now Mr Bodewes? Why my results are not OK? Just because of ignoring `foFinal` output? if so, after correcting it, how can I validate them? I'm sorry for my pestering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77436/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-abraham).

Comment: _Deterministic schemes always pad, even if you provide exactly one block of data_ : the `doFinal()` method returns `8` for all 8 byte length data for me. I throw the value that this method returns in the next line of it using `isoException.throwIt()` and it is `8`. Why it doesn't have padding?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [openssl doc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html):

> All the block ciphers normally use **PKCS#5** padding also known as standard block padding

This is the only supported  padding scheme.

The way around it is to use `-nopad` option and "manually" pad your input message, following the padding schemes you mentioned.