# Java Card Applet returns 6f00 while trying to encrypt a message

Tags: encryption, javacard, des

I'm trying to encrypt a key imported in my card and store it again in the same byte array.
The import_key function below receives an apdu and extracts the message KEY, then tries to encrypt it (simple DES encryption) and store it at the same place.
It seems that I have done everything necessary but unfortunately I receive 6f00 every time I uncomment the encryption part!!!
this is my code:

```
public class Encryptor extends Applet {

private byte[] KEY                                  = new byte[128];
private byte key_len                                = (byte)0;
private byte[] ENC_KEY                              = new byte[32];
private byte enc_key_len                            = (byte)0;

Cipher MyCipher;
private byte[] TheDES_Key = new byte[24];
DESKey MyDES1Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES, false);
byte ConfiguredKeyLength = 0;

{...}

private void import_key(APDU apdu) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maximum_buffer_len];
    buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
    key_len = buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_LC];
    apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
    Util.arrayCopy(buffer, (short) (ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA), KEY, (short) 0, (short) key_len);

    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(ENC_KEY, (short) 0, TheDES_Key, (short) 0, (short) enc_key_len);

    MyDES1Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);
    MyCipher.init(MyDES1Key, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);

    byte[] CipheredData = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 32,JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    MyCipher.doFinal(KEY, (short)0,(short)key_len,CipheredData,(short)0);
    Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(CipheredData,(short)0,KEY,(short)0,(short)key_len);

    return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your Lc greater than 127? If yes, `(short) key_len` is a negative value, which might cause the exception. Try `(short) (key_len & 0xFF)` instead and you will get what you want (a short of value 128).

Comment: Any progress? Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
DESKey MyDES1Key = (DESKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES, false);
```

you defined length of `MyDES1Key` as `LENGTH_DES` that is `8` bytes, while in the line:

`MyDES1Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);`

You are filling it with a `24` bytes variable!

In the other word you must replace `KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES` with `KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES3_3KEY`.

Comment: @M.Jalali Why did you defined `private byte key_len  = (byte)0;` and `private byte enc_key_len = (byte)0;`? Why those are assigned with zero? The `arrayCopy` methods do nothing because of these values as length.

Comment: those contain the length of KEY and ENC_KEY which are received somewhere else.

Comment: Throw an exception right before the line `MyDES1Key.setKey(TheDES_Key, (short) 0);` and throw an specific value other than `0x6D00` and run the program to check if the problem is before than that line or after it :)

Comment: I've found where the problem occurs, that is in the line [MyCipher.doFinal(KEY, (short)0,(short)key_len,CipheredData,(short)0);] but I don't know why it happens!

Comment: @M.Jalali Mr.Vojta is right. And also key_length must be shorter than `32` bytes. because the length of `CipheredData` variable is `32` bytes. And also, `key_length` must be dividable by 8 if your algorithm mode is `NO_PAD`

Comment: can you lead me to write a method which gives data and key and returns the encrypted message in data input?

Comment: @Abraham I could not find the answer there! that has the same problem as mine! 6F00

Comment: @M.Jalali Did you installed the same program that Vojta suggested you(Without any changeds) and you still receive `6f00`?

Comment: @Abraham I tiried your code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148089/java-card-des-generator-applet-output-is-different-from-online-tools-output). It works perfect but even copy/paste to my code returns 6f00! and It drives me crazy :/

Comment: @Abraham Yes I installed the same applet and it is installed successfully, but I could not send any successful apdu! but your code works correctly and I don't know why it doesn't work on mine!!!

Comment: @M.Jalali Is that possible for you to post your complete program without any change in the question and let me test it on my own computer?

Comment: @Abraham Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98112/discussion-between-m-jalali-and-abraham).